# Alternative for Contains when writing SQL for Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Is there a way to write a SQL query that looks in a Data Extension field for a contains X value

I have a Data Extension that has a Description field and i want to write a query that extracts any record that contains the word geo-spatial

I have tried Like but it didnt work
Example of query i have:

```
Select 
        i.[subscriber key] as subscriber_key
       ,i.[First Name]
       ,i.[Last Name]
       ,c.Description
from 
      ENT.Case_salesforce_2 as c 
      Left Outer Join contact i on i.[Subscriber Key] = c.ContactId
where 
     c.Description like 'geo-spatial'
```

Example of the data in the field is: Requests to change geo-spatial block information. Please close this case when the block has been updated.........

I cant do an exact match as the copy changes for each submission but always will have geo-spatial in the records i need
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the LIKE operator correctly. You need to use the `%` before and after your string 'geo-spatial'.

The `%` replaces all characters before and after 'geo-spatial'.

Try this query:

```
Select i.[subscriber key] as subscriber_key 
       , i.[First Name] 
       , i.[Last Name] 
       , c.Description 
from ENT.Case_salesforce_2 as c 
Left Outer Join contact i on i.[Subscriber Key] = c.ContactId 
where c.Description like '%geo-spatial%'
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked great